# Pourquoi 'chef de projet' et 'ingénieur projet' ?

Tags: science, université

L'autre jour j'ai assisté à une présentation (niveau mémoire master). Les élèves avaient un diaporama récapitulant leur projet. Ils ont écrit :

> Chef de projet : John Dupont

> Ingénieurs projet : John Doe et Richard Roe

Je ne sais pas pourquoi ils ont utilisé 'de' pour chef et pas pour ingénieurs. Mes collègues m'ont dit qu'il s'agit des tournures figées mais je me demande s'il y a une explication.

Comment: « ils ont 'de' pour chef » : « avoir » est un anglicisme dans ce contexte.

Comment: « Je n'ai pas pourquoi » : ne se dit  pas  (je ne **sais** pas pourquoi).

Comment: On utilise aussi *ingéneur **de** projet*, [par exemple ici](https://www.jobijoba.com/fr/fiches-metiers/Ingenieur+de+projet)

Comment: @RogerVadim … sauf que  la réponse commence par *L'ingénieur **de** projet est un **chef de** projet dans le secteur industriel*, … »

Comment: Chef ***de*** projet == Responsable ***du*** projet — · — Ingénieur [métier associé] == technicien supérieur spécialisé dans ***le*** métier du projet ou rattaché à ***ce*** projet.

Comment: « Technicien supérieur spécialisé... ». Merci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add the useful comments as an answer.

> Chef de projet == Responsable du projet — · — Ingénieur [métier associé] == technicien supérieur spécialisé dans le métier du projet ou rattaché à ce projet. –
> @Personne

> La tournure "métier + specialisation" est aussi classique : ingénieur structure, responsable achats, technicien radio... Je ne sais pas s'il s'agit réellement d'anglicismes ou plutôt de raccourcis courants dans le milieu professionnel. Le TLfI donne l'exemple "d'ingénieur-système" comme datant de 1973 même s'il prend un tiret. –
> @guillaume31

> (...) What is sure is that we do not say in French un projet ingénieur, we would never say un chef projet and even less un projet chef. @jlliagre

Answer (score -1):

Oui, je dirais que 'chef de projet' est une tournure classique, et que 'ingenieur projet' est un anglicisme (project engineer)

D'ailleurs en anglais, on retrouve parfois l'inverse pour certain titres hérités du francais, par exemple 'consul general'

Comment: La tournure "métier + specialisation" est aussi classique : *ingénieur structure*, *responsable achats*, *technicien radio*... Je ne sais pas s'il s'agit réellement d'anglicismes ou plutôt de raccourcis courants dans le milieu professionnel. Le TLfI donne l'exemple "d'ingénieur-système" comme datant de 1973 même s'il prend un tiret.